# Applying borders to InlineShape applies to table it resides in rather than image

Tags: vba, ms-word, border

So I have some InlineShapes that resides in a table in WORD. I'm trying to take all the InlineShapes in the third column of the table and apply a border around them. Unfortunately for the life of me I can't figure out how to apply it to the picture rather than the cell of the table.

[image: Picture of Current border application here]

Here is my code:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Columns(3).Select

For Each iPicture In Selection.InlineShapes
    With iPicture
        .Borders.Enable = True
        .Borders.OutsideColor = wdColorRed
        .Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    End With
Next
```

I also tried putting the following code inside `With iPicture` but didn't seem to make a difference, still drawing a border around the cell rather than the picture.

```
With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
    .Color = wdColorRed
End With

With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
    .Color = wdColorRed
End With

With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
    .Color = wdColorRed
End With

With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
    .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .LineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
    .Color = wdColorRed
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tests were inconclusive. Some objects received a border; with others, the border was applied to the cell.

In all the latter cases, however, if I placed a space after the object (at the end of the cell) the border was applied correctly.

I therefore suspect that it has something to do with the hidden paragraph mark at the end of a cell that's somehow, sometimes, getting picked up by the `InlineShape` object.

The following sample code adds a space after each `InlineShape` if the number of the characters in the cell is less than or equal to two (contains only the `InlineShape` and end-of-cell marker).

Inserting the space collapses the selection. Therefore the table and selected column are noted at the beginning and that column re-selected after that action. If the space is a problem for you, add code that goes through and removes it after the borders have been created.

```
Sub BorderInlineShapes()
    Dim sel As Word.Selection
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim colNr As Long
    Dim tbl As Word.Table

    Set sel = Selection
    If sel.Tables.Count = 1 Then
        Set tbl = sel.Tables(1)
        colNr = sel.Information(wdEndOfRangeColumnNumber)
        For Each ils In sel.InlineShapes
            If Not ils.Borders.Enable Then ils.Borders.Enable = True
            If ils.Range.Cells.Count > 0 Then
                Set rng = ils.Range
                If rng.Cells(1).Range.Characters.Count <= 2 Then
                    rng.InsertAfter " "
                    tbl.Columns(colNr).Select
                End If
            End If
            ils.Borders.OutsideColor = wdColorRed
            ils.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth075pt
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Cindy for all the testing. I tried your solution by adding a space either before or after the picture and it started placing the border around the picture rather than the cell as intended.